# Exclude lines with null values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I've got an output of the request which gives me all information that I needed. But in the output result I've got an empty lines however they should be excluded from the output because they aren't contain full masive of the information.
`drXY:null` and `distInM:null` - are shouldn't be outputted
They should be filled by cordinates like in the example below

```
 drXY:50.34982681,30.95430183 | fromXY:50.33421340,30.98074794 | distInM:2561
 drXY:50.35084534,30.95514488 | fromXY:50.33421340,30.98074794 | distInM:2597
```

This is what i've got

```
 drXY:46.46833420,30.74011040 | fromXY:46.48067899,30.74296405 | distInM:1390
                              | fromXY:50.37433094,30.92993617 |
 drXY:50.36543655,30.92126656 | fromXY:50.36977360,30.92906177 | distInM:735
```

I've tried this

```
select substring(query from '(drXY:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)') as drxy,
       substring(query from '(fromXY:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)') as fromxy,
       substring(query, '(distInM:[0-9]+)') as dist
from (
  select additional_data -> 'cd' ->> 'Query' as query
  from stat_event where
  additional_data -> 'cd' ? 'Query' and
  value is null and
  action = 'ProposalShown' and
  created between '2019-08-04' and '2019-08-05') t;
```

Comment: Your query contains JSON operations but your example does not show such. Please add your simplified(!) data set and the expected output. How should the NULL values be filled, where do the data should come from?

Comment: Null data shouldn't be filled. This is a case that i should EXCLUDE null values from the output, and get only filled values like in examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with the derived values, we can put your expression in a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) and then work with the derived columns like normal.

```
with (
    select substring(query from '(drXY:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)') as drxy,
           substring(query from '(fromXY:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)') as fromxy,
           substring(query, '(distInM:[0-9]+)') as dist
    from (
      select additional_data -> 'cd' ->> 'Query' as query
      from stat_event where
      additional_data -> 'cd' ? 'Query' and
      value is null and
      action = 'ProposalShown' and
      created between '2019-08-04' and '2019-08-05'
    ) t
) as derived
select *
from derived
where drxy is not null
  and fromxy is not null
  and dist is not null;
```

Note: things would be easier and faster if `query` was broken up into its derived columns on insert and update.

Comment: When i try to copy paste this code i get syntax error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: with (

Comment: @SemyonKolesnikov I have cleverly included a simple syntax error so you'd have to understand what you're copying before running it! ...ok, no, I goofed. But you should be able to fix it on your own. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html